# Problem with starting .net core application. Unable to start Kestrel on port 80

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

When i try to start an application on port 80 i get error.

I've tried to start this app on different port and it worked but when i choose port <1100 it have some problems.

I use this command:

dotnet appname.dll --urls="http://localhost:80"

And the error looks like this:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>        Unable to bind to http://localhost:80 on the IPv4 loopback interface: 'Permission denied'.
>   warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>        Unable to bind to http://localhost:80 on the IPv6 loopback interface: 'Permission denied'.
>   crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
>        Unable to start Kestrel.
>   System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://localhost:80. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Permission denied) (Permission denied) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Permission denied
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass21_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: Failed to bind to address http://localhost:80. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Permission denied) (Permission denied) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Permission denied
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, String callerName)
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()
>   v   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.<>c__DisplayClass21_0`1.<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindEndpointAsync(ListenOptions endpoint, AddressBindContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.LocalhostListenOptions.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
>    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)

Comment: Have you tried running in an administrator console?

Comment: @JonasMH Hi, no i didn't. It worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe also look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671199/kestrel-unable-to-start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to this problem was @JonasMH comment.
"Have you tried running in an administrator console?"
It worked for me!